# Define a default style to workspace in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I would like to know if there's a way to define a default style to a whole workspace in GeoServer? For instance each time a raster is published will have the default style we defined using YSLD.

Comment: I don't think so but try calling it raster and see if that works